# How to trigger postback in java

Tags: java, asp.net, web-scraping, web-crawler, postback

I'm building a webcrawler in java. But I don't know how to trigger postback. This is first time that I building a webcrawler. If I ask a stupid question, forgive me, please.

```
<a id="lbtnNextPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbtnNextPage','')">nextPage</a>
```

Comment: I code crawler in java. I search in google for a few days. Maybe I use wrong keywords?

Comment: @user3927463 Java and JavaScript are very different things - the similar names are just unfortunate. What you want to search for is JavaScript.

Comment: @KevinMain I know Java and JavaScript are very different. Can Java build a webcrawler?

Comment: @user3927463 Short answer - Yes. Long answer - https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/